# x11vnc stuck at connecting loop

Tags: networking, server, vnc

I am quite new to linux and I have this issue that I wasnt able to find a solution to.

Issue:

When I connect to my server running x11vnc as soon as I turn my server on, everything is good to go until I stop from doing anything, like mouse movement and such for few minutes. When that happens and I get back to doing stuff, the VNC is still connected BUT its not receiving any screen updates anymore, but the keyboard or mouse input is still sent and received by the server! If I disconnect and try to connect back again, its stuck at a INFINITE connecting loop!

Now, the same issue happens even if I don't do anything before I am connected to my server (x11vnc).

Basically, the issue is, once my server is left to idle for a couple of minutes, the x11vnc stops sending the screen to the connected VNC client and accepting incoming connections.

The way I get it to work again is if I move the mouse or press something on the keyboard that is connected directly to my server. Same case as if a computer was sleeping, like a windows PC.

How do I fix this issue? I need the x11vnc to be always active, no idling, always ready to accept new connections, if there is a idle mode. 
Here is a x11vnc service file that starts x11vnc:

```
[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
Restart-sec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

PS: When the issue happens, applications and such don't stop working, there is no screensaver and such, its not sleeping, the screen doesn't go black, everything is functioning as normal. This issue is most likely with x11vnc it self.